# Como capturar todas as exceções em Python?

Tags: python, exceção

Como capturar toda e qualquer exceção em Python? Há alguma palavra-chave para isso?

Como no Java que basta fazer um

```
try {
}
catch(Exception ex) {
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É a mesma coisa. Só usar um [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```
try:
    aluma_coisa()
except Exception as e:
    fazer_algo(e)
```

Comment: para ver a exceção pode usar print(str(e))

Comment: Então Python, tem uma hierarquia semelhante ao Java? Vou estudar melhor.

Comment: Isso @Wilker. Só que a Exception mais genérica do Python é a `BaseException`. Porém ela captura erros como `KeyboardInterrup` e `SystemExit` e geralmente não se quer isso.

Answer (score 4):

Vou tentar acrescentar algo à resposta do @jbueno, visto que existem mais alguns detalhes no levantamento de exceções do Python. Só vou expor aqui o que considero mais importante, elucidando, principalmente, com exemplos. Explicação completa pode ser vista na documentação, [nesse link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html).

Exception é a classe base para todas as exceções, se voce tem dúvidas de que o código pode levantar uma exceção, use o bloco try-except

```
try:
    f = open('file','w')
    f.write('testing Exception handling')
except IOError:
    print ("Erro, arquivo não encontrado ou erro nos dados")
else:
    print ('Sucesso na escrita do arquivo')
```

> **Clausula Except**

**Sem exceções** 
Veja que voce pode usar a clausula except sem explicitar a exceção, com isso voce vai considerar todas as exceções, mas isso não é considerado uma boa prática de programação, porque o desenvolvedor não consegue identificar a "raiz" do problema, em python tente sempre seguir uma das declarações da PEP 20 **"Explicito é melhor que implicito".**

**Multiplas exceções**
A cláusula *except* também aceita multiplas exceções.

```
try:
  # implementação
except (KeyError, IndexError)
  # Se houver qualque exception, execute esse bloco
...
```

> **Clausula try-finally**

Voce pode usar finally junto com o try quando voce quer que um bloco seja executado de qualquer forma, ocorrendo exceção ou não.

```
try:
    f = open('file','w')
    f.write('testing Exception handling')
finally:
    # Esse bloco vai ser execudo de qualquer forma
```

> **Exemplos adicionais**

Com try-finally-except.

```
try:
    f = open('file','w')
    try:
        f.write('testing Exception handling')
    finally:
        print ('Ok, fechando o arquivo')
        f.close()
except IOError:
    print "Erro arquivo ausente ou corrompido"
```

Um exemplo combinando exceções.

```
import sys

try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except OSError as err:
    print("Erro de sistema operacional: {0}".format(err))
except ValueError:
    print("Impossível converter dados do arquivo em um inteiro.")
except:
    print("Erro inesperado:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

Nesse exemplo, apresenta-se as informações da exceção.

```
def multply(x,y):
    try:
       r = (x*y)
    except Exception as e:
       print('Erro :')
       print ('Tipo: ', type(e))
       print ('Argumentos: ', e.args)
       print (e)
    else:
        return r

>>> multply('a','b')
Erro :
Tipo:  <class 'TypeError'>
Argumentos:  ("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'",)
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

> Easter Egg

Abra o console do python e digite:

```
>>> import this
```

**Referencia** 
[Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html). 
 
[PEP 20, O Zen do Python.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)