# Achar o maior valor de um arquivo qualquer em python

Tags: python, txt

Boa noite DEVs!

Eu estou tendo certas dificuldades em manipular arquivos em python.
Eu possuo um arquivo TXT com números do tipo Float.

Exemplo:

> **numeros.txt**
>
> 10 130 20
> 77 23
> 9 10 20.26 -20.26 2

Tendo este dados em mãos, eu tenho de percorrer linha por linha, verificar se o arquivo é vazio ou não, se for vazio eu tenho de achar o maior valor dentro do arquivo e a média deles, e é aqui que a minha dúvida ganha forças, como eu consigo recuperar estes dados para realizar os cálculos? eu tentei salvar em um vet, porém os dados passam a ser strings e não aceitam a conversão para Float.

Estarei deixando o meu código abaixo:

```
#Ler o nome do arquivo
#Abrir o arquivo caso exista
#Verificar o Maior valor possivel
#Verificar a Média dos valores
#Imprimir média e Valores


def pulaLinha ():
    print('\n')



arq  = open("numeros.txt", "r") #ABRE O ARQUIVO TXT

########################################
#CALCULAR O TOTAL DE LINHAS DO ARQUIVO|#
########################################

text = arq.readlines()# GUARDA TODOS OS DADOS DO ARQUIVO
tot  = 0 #TOTAL DE LINHAS
for i in text: #CALCULA O TOTAL DE LINHA DO ARQUIVO
    tot = tot+1 #SALVA O TOTAL EM UM ACUMULADOR

########################################
#VERIFICAR SE O ARQUIVO É VAZIO OU NÃO #
########################################

if (tot == 0):#SE TOT DE LINHAS FOR IGUAL A 0
    print("ARQUIVO VAZIO! ") #IMPRIME O ERRO
    arq.close() # FECHA ARQUIVO
    exit()

#SE O TOT DE LINHAS FOR MAIOR QUE 0
for linha in text:#ARMAZENA OS VALORES EM LINHA
    print(linha, end=" ") #IMPRIME OS VALORES DE LINHA // IMPRIME O ARQUIVO


vet = []
for j in text:
    vet.append(j)
    
    



arq.close()#FECHA O ARQUIVO TXT
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei grato.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: É um número por linha? Tens numa das linhas `9 10 20.26 -20.26 2` o que é suposto ser isso?

Comment: @Miguel- Existe um arquivo, este arquivo possui linhas, eu quero achar o maior valor dentro do arquivo, ele pode estar em qualquer local, e também achar a média dos valores.

Comment: Pelo seu texto, dá a entender que será apenas um número por linha, mas o conteúdo do arquivo que postou diz o contrário. Foi isso que o Miguel perguntou: será apenas um número por linha ou pode existir mais de um na mesma linha?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, vou colocar os passos para vc pegar os resultados desejados, não me preocupei com detalhes, tais como se o arquivo existe ou se esta vazio, isso é com vc ([Esse link pode adjuar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195850/como-capturar-todas-as-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-python/195937#195937)), segue a logica principal:

```
from scipy import mean

# Load File
lf = list(open('numeros.txt','r'))

# Remove /n
lf = [s.rstrip() for s in lf]

# Convert into a list of list
lfl = [_str.split(' ') for _str in lf]

# flaten
fflaten = [float(n) for sub_list in lfl for n in sub_list]

print ('Média: ', mean(fflaten) )
print ('Vl Máximo: ', max(fflaten))
print ('Vl Minimo: ', min(fflaten))

Média:  28.1
Vl Máximo:  130.0
Vl Minimo:  -20.26
```

[Veja um jupyter notebook desse codigo funcionando nesse link.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/maxmeanmin/notebook)

> Em tempo:
>   Para tratar exceções do tipo se o arquivo existe ou não, [veja os exemplos nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195850/como-capturar-todas-as-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-python/195937#195937).

Comment: Neste caso eu sou obrigado a usar scipy?

Comment: Scipy foi só para usar a função mean, se vc não  precisar dela pode dispensar, ou pode fazer sua propria funcao para calcuar a media.

Comment: Ah sim, muito obrigado :D

Comment: +1 pelo list(open()). Nunca vi esse uso. Sempre uso open().readlines()

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, vamos considerar que o arquivo pode possuir qualquer tipo de conteúdo (tanto números quanto textos), sem um formato definido. Isto é, podem haver múltiplas linhas e múltiplos valores em cada linha, podendo variar a quantidade de números nas mesmas. Por exemplo, o arquivo `numeros.txt` dado na pergunta:

> **numeros.txt**
>
> 10 130 20
> 77 23
> 9 10 20.26 -20.26 2

O código deverá identificar corretamente os seguintes valores: 10, 130, 20, 77, 23, 9, 10, 20.26, -20,26, 2.

Para tal, fazemos:

```
import re

# busca os valores reais no arquivo numeros.txt:
numeros = [float(i) for i in re.findall(r"-?\d+\.?\d*", open("numeros.txt").read())]

# Exibe a lista de números:
print(numeros)
```

A saída será:

```
[10.0, 130.0, 20.0, 77.0, 23.0, 9.0, 10.0, 20.26, -20.26, 2.0]
```

O maior valor é encontrado pela função `max`:

```
>>> print("Maior valor:", max(numeros))
Maior valor: 130.0
```

E a média é calculada dividindo a soma dos números pela quantidade:

```
>>> print("Média:", sum(numeros)/len(numeros))
Média: 28.1
```

O código completo, então, fica:

```
import re

numeros = [float(i) for i in re.findall(r"-?\d+\.?\d*", open("numeros.txt").read())]

if numeros:
    print("Maior valor:", max(numeros))
    print("Média:", sum(numeros)/len(numeros))
else:
    print("Nenhum número encontrado")
```

O código equivalente, só que mais legível para humanos:

```
import re

# Expressão regular de números reais:
pattern = re.compile(r"-?\d+\.?\d*")

# Busca todos os números do arquivo:
with open("numeros.txt") as f:
    numeros = pattern.findall(f.read())
    
# Converte os números para float:
numeros = [float(i) for i in numeros]

if numeros:
    print("Maior valor:", max(numeros))
    print("Média:", sum(numeros)/len(numeros))
else:
    print("Nenhum número encontrado")
```

> O código funcionando pode ser visto [aqui](https://repl.it/H1to/0).