# Ficheiro txt para lista em python

Tags: python

Tenho vários ficheiros com valores da forma:

```
0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1
0.4375    0.8674    0.0090         1
0.4400    0.8682    0.0082         1
```

Como faço para carregar esses ficheiros em Python na forma

```
   [[0.4350, 0.8798, 0.0099, 1],
    [0.4375, 0.8674, 0.0090, 1],
    [0.4400, 0.8682, 0.0082, 1]]
```

para poder fazer um gráfico a partir deles?

Answer (score 3):

Considerando que o arquivo possua apenas dados no formato mencionado, podemos transformá-los em uma lista de listas [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Utilizando de boas práticas para [abrir e manipular](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) arquivos, o código para processar esses dados fica assim:

```
with open('dados.txt', 'r') as f:
    results = [[float(entry) for entry in line.split()] for line in f.readlines()]
    print(results)
```

**Resultado**

```
[[0.435, 0.8798, 0.0099, 1.0], [0.4375, 0.8674, 0.009, 1.0], [0.44, 0.8682, 0.0082, 1.0]]
```

**Como Funciona**

Primeiro iteramos em todas as linhas do arquivo no `for` mais externo. Para cada linha do arquivo, executa-se o `split` (do string) para separar os valores em uma nova lista utilizada pelo `for` interno. Depois a função `float` faz o cast de string para float.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos considerar o arquivo chamado **valores.txt** com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
0.4350  
0.8798  
0.0099 1 0.4375 0.8674 
0.0090 1 0.4400 0.8682  
0.0082 1
```

Então "desenvolvi" o código abaixo, que na verdade é uma parte [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200635/achar-o-maior-valor-de-um-arquivo-qualquer-em-python/200650#200650).

### Código

```
# Load File
lf = list(open('valores.txt','r'))

# Remove /n
lf = [s.rstrip() for s in lf]

# Convert into a list of list
lfl = [_str.split(' ') for _str in lf]

# Apresenta os resultados 
print (lfl)
```

### Resultado:

```
[['0.4350'], ['0.8798'], ['0.0099', '1', '0.4375', '0.8674'], 
 ['0.0090', '1', '0.4400', '0.8682'], ['0.0082', '1']]
```

---

[DEMO EM JUPYTER NOTEBOOK.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/txt-to-float/notebook)